# Driver error using mysql-mariadb10 and Java 11 in Intellij IDE

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea, mariadb, java-11

I got this error in compiling my Java code: **org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver.**

Java mysql driver that added in my project structure: **mariadb-java-client-2.5.4.jar**

the version of mariadb is **:10.3.21-MariaDB-2**

JDK version : 11.0.6

OS: 5.4.0-kali3-amd64

Comment: Could you share the full stacktrace?

Comment: @SHoko java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:602)
 at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:178)
 at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
 at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
 at java.base/java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:333)
 at JavaMysqlSelectExample.main(JavaMysqlSelectExample.java:19)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver` is the legacy class name used to backward compatibility with the predecessor of Connector/J ([and is present in old MySQL drivers](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-class-name.html)), in [new ones (8.0)](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-usagenotes-connect-drivermanager.html) the class name used is `om.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver`.

But, when we use the MariaDB driver superior to 1.2.0 ([in your case 2.5.4](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-j/#server-compatibility)) we need to use **[`org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver`](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/about-mariadb-connector-j/#getting-a-new-connection)** as class name.